# pandas not in, in and between

Tags: numpy, pandas

pd.**version**
'0.14.0'

I need to do a not in statement for a column in a dataframe.

for the isin statement I use the following to filter for codes that I need:

```
h1 = df1[df1['nat_actn_2_3'].isin(['100','101','102','103','104'])]
```

I want to do a not in or not equal to (not sure which one is used for python) statement for another column.

So I tried the following:

```
h1 = df1[df1['csc_auth_12'].notin(['N6M','YEM','YEL','YEM'])]

h1 = df1[df1['csc_auth_12'] not in (['N6M','YEM','YEL','YEM'])]
```

and:

```
h1.query(['N6M','YEM','YEL','YEM'] not in ['csc_auth_12'])
```

I really want to filter out the N6M, YEM, YEL and YEM from the data set.

I'm also interested in how to do an between statement.

So for the following I had to manually type in all the 500 codes.  I would like to do something like:

```
h1 = df1[df1['nat_actn_2_3'].isin['100','102'] and isbetween [500 & 599])]
```

but this is what I have:

```
h1 = df1[df1['nat_actn_2_3'].isin(['100','101','102','103','104','107','108','112','115','117','120','122','124','128',
                             '130','132','132','140','141','142','143','145','146','147','148','149','170','171',
                             '172','173','179','190','198','199','501','502','503','504','505','506','507','508',
                             '509','510','511','512','513','514','515','516','517','518','519','520','521','522',
                             '523','524','525','526','527','528','529','530','531','532','533','534','535','536',
                             '537','538','539','540','541','542','543','544','545','546','547','548','549','550',
                             '551','552','553','554','555','556','557','558','559','560','561','562','563','564',
                             '565','566','567','568','569','570','571','572','573','574','575','576','577','578',
                             '579','580','581','582','583','584','585','586','587','588','589','590','591','592',
                             '593','594','595','596','597','598','599','702','721','740','953','955'])]
```

Any suggestions?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

negate the boolean condition using `~` to invert the mask:

```
h1 = df1[~df1['nat_actn_2_3'].isin(['100','101','102','103','104'])]
```

`notin` and `not in`, the former doesn't exist and the latter will likely raise a `ValueError` or ambiguous value error as you're trying to use `in` with an array and pandas does not work like that.

For the second question you need to compound your boolean conditions like so:

```
h1 = df1[(df1['nat_actn_2_3'].isin['100','102']) | ((df1['nat_acctn_2_3'] > 500) & (df1['nat_actn_2_3'] < 599))]
```

So I'm assuming from your text you want rows that are either equal to 100/102 or between 500 and 599 (unclear if you're including those values but you can just change to `>=` and `<=` respectively).

Here you use the bitwise operators `&` and `|` for `and` and `or` respectively, also you need to wrap `()` around each condition due to operator precedence

Comment: Thanks EdChum!  Perfect!