# Pandas analogue of SQL's "NOT IN" operator

Tags: python, pandas

Suprisingly, i can't find an analogue of SQL's "NOT IN" operator in pandas DataFrames.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'a':[6,8,3,9,5],
                       'b':['II','I','I','III','II']})

B = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

I want all rows from `A`, which `a` doesn't contain values from `B`'s `c`.
Something like:

```
A = A[ A.a not in B.c]
```

Comment: this is really a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in you just negate the `isin` using `~` or even this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980087/pandas-not-in-in-and-between

Comment: while this is, in concept, a duplicate, the other question does not contain the phrase "Not In"... allowing this question to stay open will be helpful for others searching on that exact phrase.

Comment: @JDLong the other question does have in the title not in though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980087/pandas-not-in-in-and-between

Comment: @EdChum That's true, but a lot of people search for similar  answers, referencing to SQL operators.

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html) probably need additional examples to cover this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are really close - need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `~` for negate boolean mask - also instead `list` use `Series` `B.c`:

```
print (~A.a.isin(B.c))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

A = A[~A.a.isin(B.c)]
print (A)
   a    b
0  6   II
1  8    I
3  9  III
```